# Check force close and exceptions of other applications

Tags: android

In Android I want to check the force close and exceptions of other applications. Is it possible?

Comment: there are many applications that provides the device Log.if we read these log i think we can trace atleast force close of the other applications.

Answer (score 0):

No. As you can read in the [Android Security Overview](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/#the-application-sandbox), apps are isolated from each other and not able to force close other apps or read their logs/exceptions.